# pypy failing to load jupyter notebook... why?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pypy

I am trying to load jupyter notebook with PyPy. I have done it already on different machines and I never got any problem. This time, however, (on an iMac with OSX 10.11.16) I am getting the following [error message](http://pastebin.com/aCcnFQhQ):
This is the script I use to load the notebook with PyPy:

```
import re
import sys

from IPython import start_ipython

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
```

I run it from bash: `pypy script.py notebook`
If I run it without `notebook`, the IPython session starts as it is supposed to, so the issue must be related to the notebook but I can figure it out. Of course, `zeromq` is installed, but I have no idea what `headers` in the error message refers to... Any clue on how to solve this?

P.S. I have used `pypy -m pip install jupyter` to install it.

Answer (score 1):

"zeromq headers" means what is necessary for *developing with*, as opposed to only *using*, the zeromq library.  It may be in some "zeromq-dev" package or similar, depending on what distribution system you use on your OS/X.

Normally you'd get such an error when trying to do `pip install`, but in this case, "zmq" is written using the old CFFI style, deprecated since 2015; as a result it requires the headers at run-time.

Comment: So.. how can I solve my problem? Shall I install some "zeromq-dev" package?